# typescript option for iterator and spread operator

Tags: typescript

I would like to call the iterator of the type below

```
type datetimeT = { [key: number]: string };
```

If a create an object this way

```
let example: dateTimeT = {1: 'A', 2: 'B'};
```

The spread operator `...example` is not recognized because the type doesn't have `[Symbol.iterator]()` method

My ts option are

```json
  "target": "es6",
  "module": "esnext",
  "lib": [
    "dom",
    "dom.iterable",
    "esnext",
    "es2017"
  ]
```

What must I do?

Comment: Add a `Symbol.iterator` method, just like the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are not automatically iterable in Javascript, it has nothing to do with your TSConfig. Every type that you want to be iterable *must* implement an iterator method:

```js
type MyIterType = {
  [key: number]: string
} & Iterable<string>

const foo: MyIterType = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  *[Symbol.iterator] () {
    const values = Object.values(this)
    while (values.length) {
      yield values.pop()
    }
  }
}

const arr = [...foo] // ['b', 'a']
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSwICcAq5oF4oG8BQUUA2gNYQgBcUAdgK4C2ARigLpUDOwyAltQOZ4AvlABkURCgCGjADYQAPJx78AfHjwBjAPbVOUAGZatVOBLQYo2fIQAMVAOST7AGgJQAjA8Yu3AKiIAyiBMWjIAdNxIyJLAWsgsUAAUAJS4boTausBQAG6SMrQQ7JZQAPKMAFYQGsBheQVFicAAFtzsyelQAO6tckn1hexhcvwtqdaEkyDcEDIAJrn5g2FgWmApnYJuW1uaOnqSyMglRGFnhloJAPRXxPbezlCO9ix4QA)

Comment: Even easier to implement: `*[Symbol.iterator] () { yield* Object.values(this) }`

Comment: @VLAZ I did not know about [yield*expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*), thanks for the tip!

Comment: It delegates to another iterable. `yield* arr;` is more ore less the same as `for (const item of arr) yield item;`. It just means "yield everything from this other iterable"

Comment: I found it on MDN right as you were posting that lol. Thanks again, useful!

Comment: Thanks but how would you create the "Iterable" function ?

Comment: @aabb not sure what you mean, I *did* create it, it's the method defined by the key `Symbol.iterator`.

Comment: I get it thank you !